# Unsure about answering-self question?

Tags: discussion

Seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) I though this thing was promoted, and for avoiding for the question becoming boring, I didn't answer it suddenly and waited and I did mentioned that I knew the answer, maybe it's just misunderstanding that I don't know the answer. Anyways, what's the state/condition regarding such things?

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176644/unspecific-function-integration) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176622/differential-equation-sin2x-left-frac-rm-dy-rm-dx-sqrt-tan-x-ri). I edited one to include answer in question, I just didn't edited other just because.

Comment: related http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15017/can-i-post-a-question-and-an-answer-just-because-i-think-it-helps-others

Comment: Most of the time, you should not post a question on math.SE if you already know the answer. That is something that the StackExchange corporation encourages on other StackExchange sites, but it has never been a significant part of *this* site. And, in particular, this is not a site for "puzzles" or "challenges".  The following post actually has no question at all: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176622/differential-equation-sin2x-left-frac-rm-dy-rm-dx-sqrt-tan-x-ri - because "I have solved this" is not a question. A question would be something that you want to know that you don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-answering a question means that you actually post an answer to your question, not that you had already solved the question in the past.  Thus, your second link isn't a "self-answered question" by any measure.

Instead of editing the question to include an answer, it is best to *post an answer* to the question, **and** place a note in the question saying "this is a self-answered question."  The note in the question reduces the likelihood that someone closes or downvotes by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

[Puzzle Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4233/442) are allowed in math.se ... But include the information in the original post that you know the answer!

[HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351333/evaluation-of-a-continued-fraction) is an example of mine.